# Can PostgreSQL join to a stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql

In SQL Server and Oracle, joining to (or selecting from) stored procedures that return a resultset is not supported.

Is it possible in PostgreSQL?

If so, a followup question is:  is it possible, perhaps via [foreign data wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers), to join to a stored procedure within an MS SQL Server database??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PostgreSQL can join to a stored procedure (function). Tables and rows to get us started.

```
create schema test;
create table test.test_a (
  id integer primary key
);

insert into test.test_a values
(1), (2);

create table test.test_b (
  id integer references test.test_a,
  n integer not null,
  primary key (id, n)
);

insert into test.test_b values 
(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2);
```

A simple function.

```
create or replace function test.return_test_b ()
  returns table (
            id integer, 
            n integer
          ) as
$$
    select * from test.test_b
$$ language sql;
```

Now you can join directly.

```
select A.id, B.n from test.test_a A
inner join test.return_test_b() B on A.id = B.id;
```

```
id  n
--
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
```